# Changing css dynamically

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have css like so:

```
.myTabs .JustForFun .ajax__tab_inner:hover 
{
    width: 109px; 
    background:  url ("/images/csc_tr.png") no-repeat 100% 0%; margin-right: 2px;
    background-color: #BBC614; 
}
```

Using javascript, jquery or asp.net code behind c# I would like to manipulate `background-color` attribute.

How can I do this, what are the pros and cons of the solution you've recommended me is what I would like to know.

Comment: Are you looking to set that dynamically on each hover, or are you trying to set that value on page load?

Comment: Have you considered using css3? It will give you nice transitions through the color change although it would not be compatible with older browsers.

Comment: @kwelch page load :) or dom object ready

Comment: @JackalopeZero I have considered css3 since it supports variables I am restricted by supporting older browsers for our client base, thats changing so maybe in the future will be cool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I did. It sets the initial value in the `css`. Then I have the `jquery` that changes the `div` on `hover`.

The first function in the is when the cursor enters and the second is when the cursor exits.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kwelch/3HSAn/)

Comment: I will accept you answer I was writing up essentially the same thing haha thanks buddy!

Answer (score 4):

In jQuery you can simply use

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".myTabs").css("background-color","your color");
    });
</script>
```

If you do it via c# code then the page will refresh.

You cannot apply attribute changes to `:hover` through javascript instead you should use `jquery.hover` function.

Comment: So I just do `$(".myTabs .JustForFun .ajax__tab_inner:hover").css("background-color","your color");`

Answer (score 2):

[Here it is using css3](http://jsfiddle.net/Kw9p4/) (adapted from a [w3schools tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_transition1)).

I know its not javascript like you asked for, but this is much easier if you are looking for simple effects.

Comment: thanks for the Jackalope the transition parameters are awesome!

Answer (score 0):

any classes with `:hover, :active` etc cannot be manipulated from javascript or jquery easily enough. The recommended alternative is to drop the `:hover` css function and us `jquery.hover` function instead.

jquery.hover:

```
$(".classOrID").hover(

    function () {
        $(this).css("YourAttribute", <%= primaryColor %>);
    } ,

    function () {
        $(this).css("YourAttribute", <%= secondaryColor %>);

    }
);
```

You may notice the `<%= primaryColor %>` this just gets the value in c# from code behind which picks it up from a color picker in my cms.

For anything with just a css change not requiring :hover I would do.

```
$('.classOrID').css('background-color', <%= primaryColor %>);
```

Or what Shoban recommended javascript solution without jquery.